# GCC can't use undefined operator=

Tags: c++, gcc, implicit-conversion

I have a code:

```
#define CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(OWNERNAME, TYPE, NAME)                   \
struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
    DWORD dummy;                                                         \
    inline operator TYPE() {                                             \
        return CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> get_##NAME ();    \
    }                                                                    \
    inline void operator=(const TYPE &src) {                             \
        CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> set_##NAME (src); \
    }                                                                    \
} NAME;

...

    class CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper
    {
        public:
        CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper, INTERFACE_CLI_ISTRINGENCODER*, defEncoder)

...

specialEncoderText.defEncoder = encoder.getIfPtr(); // getIfPtr returns exact  INTERFACE_CLI_ISTRINGENCODER*
```

and got an error:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' in 'specialEncoderText.cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder> >::defEncoder = encoder.cli::CiStringEncoderWrapper<smartPtrType>::getIfPtr [with smartPtrType = cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringEncoder>]()'
note: candidates are: void cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<smartPtrType>::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(const cli::iStringEncoder*&) [with smartPtrType = cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder>]
note:                 cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder> >::propclass_defEncoder& cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder> >::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(const cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder> >::propclass_defEncoder&)
```

It seems like the GCC tries to use default implicit operator=, which is undefined. How I can solve this problem?

I tried to define private operator= with the second signature, but ambiguity still remains.

Currently used GCC version is 4.4.1. Previously used GCC v3.4, and there was no problems with this code.

**UPD01** Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned long ULONG_PTR;
typedef char * PCHAR;

#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(DISABLE_GCC_OFFSETOF_WARNING_WORKAROUND)
    #define CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(address, type, field) ((type *)( \
                                                      (PCHAR)(address) - \
                                                      (ULONG_PTR)(&((type *)0)->field)))
#else
    #define CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(address, type, field) ((type *)( \
                                                      1+(PCHAR)(address) - \
                                                      (ULONG_PTR)(&((type *)1)->field)))
#endif


#define CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(OWNERNAME, TYPE, NAME)                   \
struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
    DWORD dummy;                                                         \
    /*propclass_##NAME() : dummy() {}*/                                      \
    inline operator TYPE() {                                             \
        return CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> get_##NAME ();    \
    }                                                                    \
    inline void operator=(const TYPE &src) {                             \
        CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> set_##NAME (src); \
    }                                                                    \
    /*private:*/                                                             \
    /*explicit propclass_##NAME(const propclass_##NAME &src) {} */            \
    /*inline void operator=(const propclass_##NAME &src) {}     */           \
                                                                         \
} NAME;


struct SomeInterface
{
 int dummy;
 void doJob() { std::cout<<"SomeInterface::doJob\n"; }
};

class CTest
{
    SomeInterface *psf;

 public:

    SomeInterface* get_defEncoder( )
       {
        return psf;
       }

    void set_defEncoder( const SomeInterface*  &_defEncoder
                       )
       {
        psf = (SomeInterface*)_defEncoder;
       }

    CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );

};

SomeInterface sf;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CTest test;

    test.defEncoder = &sf; // (SomeInterface*)0;

    SomeInterface *pif = test.defEncoder;
    pif->doJob();
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this is unanswerable withtout an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You really are using preprocessor to generate a class? Wow. On a separate note? Thy did you try to define `operator=` private, and what ambiguity you talk about? There is no match at all, despite two candidates.

Comment: What is MCVCE? And, can you explain you second note more clearly?

Comment: The "MCVE" above is a clickable link, you know. And I can't express myself more clearly other than saying I made a typo "Thy" should be "Why". It is a simple question (or two). The automatically generated operator has signature `operator=(const cli::CiStringSpecialEncoderWrapper<cli::CCliPtr<cli::iStringSpecialEncoder> >::propclass_defEncoder&)` yours is `operator=(const cli::iStringEncoder*&)`. I don't know what makes you think, when you invoke your line you match any of these. The code is hard to follow.

Comment: @BerndJacobi In order to have any success in programming you do need to be able to use websearch. Surely you can search for MCVE. To us it just seems as though you are lazy and could not be bothered to search. I hope that's not the case. And even then, Angew even took the time to leave you a clickable link. Please do take some time to learn how to use websearch. You will be much better at programming once you've learnt that skill.

Comment: As you can see, my question was updated with MCVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

g++ 4.9.0 gives these errors for your MCVE:

```
main.cpp:58:64: warning: extra ';' [-Wpedantic]
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
                                                                ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:68:21: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'CTest::propclass_defEncoder' and 'SomeInterface*')
     test.defEncoder = &sf; // (SomeInterface*)0;
                     ^
main.cpp:68:21: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:25:17: note: void CTest::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(const SomeInterface*&)
     inline void operator=(const TYPE &src) {                             \
                 ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp:25:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SomeInterface*' to 'const SomeInterface*&'
     inline void operator=(const TYPE &src) {                             \
                 ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp:19:8: note: CTest::propclass_defEncoder& CTest::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(const CTest::propclass_defEncoder&)
 struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
        ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SomeInterface*' to 'const CTest::propclass_defEncoder&'
 struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
        ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp:19:8: note: CTest::propclass_defEncoder& CTest::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(CTest::propclass_defEncoder&&)
 struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
        ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SomeInterface*' to 'CTest::propclass_defEncoder&&'
 struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
        ^
main.cpp:58:5: note: in expansion of macro 'CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW'
     CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(CTest, SomeInterface*, defEncoder );
     ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:64:14: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
              ^
main.cpp:64:31: warning: unused parameter 'argv' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])

                           ^
```

So first thing to check: are the types used when looking for `operator=` sensible?

```
no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'CTest::propclass_defEncoder'
and 'SomeInterface*')
```

Looks good so far.  Then g++ lists all the candidate functions it considered.  Is the one you expected in the list?  Yup:

```
note: void CTest::propclass_defEncoder::operator=(const SomeInterface*&)
```

And then immediately after that, it says

```
note:    no known conversion for argument 1 from 'SomeInterface*'
         to 'const SomeInterface*&'
```

Aha.  Because you're using the preprocessor, `const TYPE&` is not a reference to `const TYPE`.  It just slaps the `const` token in front, giving `const SomeInterface*&`, which is a reference to non-const pointer (to const data).  But since the input `SomeInterface*` argument does not point at const data, you can't bind that type of reference to it.

You probably meant for `operator=` to have parameter type `SomeInterface* const&`.  You could get that by putting `TYPE const&` instead of `const TYPE&` in the macro, at least for this scenario.  But to be a bit safer, you could use a `typedef` and use the actual type semantics of C++:

```
#define CLI_DECLARE_PROPERTY_RW(OWNERNAME, TYPE, NAME)                   \
struct propclass_##NAME {                                                \
    typedef TYPE property_type;                                          \
    DWORD dummy;                                                         \
    /*propclass_##NAME() : dummy() {}*/                                      \
    inline operator property_type() {                                    \
        return CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> get_##NAME ();    \
    }                                                                    \
    inline void operator=(const property_type &src) {                    \
        CLI_CONTAINING_RECORD(this, OWNERNAME, NAME)-> set_##NAME (src); \
    }                                                                    \
} NAME;
```